Linux on Windows
I'm trying to familiarize myself with linux without actually running a virtual machine or installing it directly so I did use WSL (Ubuntu) and I'm confused to why some of the script that should be running in linux won't run.
For example:
"script": {
  "start": "NODE_ENV=development eleventy --serve"
  "postinstall": "rm -rf node_modules/@types/glob"
}

instead what I did was modify the start to SET NODE_ENV=development && eleventy --serve and remove the postinstall to actually run the program.
Also I'm using nvm-windows to manage my node versions. node -v and nvm -v won't run on linux but npm -v does. See image below: (It runs normally on cmd)

Can anyone help to explain. To my knowledge both windows and linux should run inside wsl.

These are very typical messages you get when something is not installed on ubuntu/debian based releases.  It's saying that there is no executable file in the path named "nvm" or "node" nor "npm".  And it is trying to be helpful by providing suggestions on how to fix the problem by installing the packages which contain that programs.
I've no idea how being under WSL applies but, under native ubuntu, you would search for and install the missing packages with a combination of apt or snap commands.

$ apt show nodejs
$ sudo apt install nodejs

